# Compiling sass files in their respective project directories using a design system as source

Tags: sass, jekyll

I'm using jekyll as a platform for a design system. At the same time, I have a directory where I share prototypes and work in progress—on their own directories, using the design system framework——SASS files.

So, what I want to do is compile the .scss files in this directories I use for prototypes, generating an `app.scss`and this file importing the .scss files from the design system.

What I've found so far is that putting the front matter tripple dash at the begining of the file it will execute it as if it was in the _sass file, but that doesn't seem to import the .scss in the _sass directory in to the project directory.

This is the directory structure I have so far that I ideally want, but is not working:

```
jekyll-project/
├── _includes/
├── _layouts/
├── _site/
├── _sass/
|   └── design-system.scss
|       ├──Components
|          └── component_1.scss
|          └── component_2.scss
|          └── ...
└── css/
│   └── main.scss // this is what gets compiles from the _sass directory
├── projects/
    └── project_1
        └── scss
            └── app.scss // here this file will compile it's own styles to CSS + import the design-system.scss from the _sass directory in:
        └── css
            └── app.css
    └── project_2
        └── scss
            └── app.scss
        └── css
            └── app.css
    └── project_3
        └── ...
├── _config.yml
└── index.html
```

In the scss file in the project_1 folder—-and the others as well—-what I want compiled in the app.scss file:

```
1st: the compiled design-system.scss
+
2nd: the styles writen in app.scss
```

Many thanks in advance and hopefully was able to illustrate the issue understandable enough.

Comment: What is `_sass/design-system.scss` ? a file or a folder ? Can you give `app.scss` code and eventual compile error ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel `_sass` is the directory that Jekyll used to compile into CSS. `design-system.scss` is the file where I have all the imports to the components i.e. `@import 'buttons'; @import 'links'; etc`

This is the error I'm getting:
```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'experiments/portfolio-tiles/scss/app.scss':
                    File to import not found or unreadable: /design-system/design-system.scss. Load paths: /Users/ivanfrantar/Sites/design-projects-draft/_sass /Users/ivanfrantar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minima-2.5.0/_sass on...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by running the:

`sass --watch scss:css` in the project folder `scss` and in the `app.scss` `@import design-system` directly from the `_sass` directory. For instance, I'm calling the design system file:

`@import "../../../_sass/design-system/design-system.scss";` so it is the sass watch that is doing the compiling, not the engine that Jekyll use, which is what I was trying to use in the first place.

Probably not the most elegant solution, but solves the problem I was having.